# Make responsive Bootstrap navbar without hamburger menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am building a portfolio project using Bootstrap. I wanted to have the navbar be responsive but not use the default hamburger menu. Instead, I have a media query that changes the text links into icons. However, when the screen is resized to 767 and below, the icons collapse into a second row. I want them to just get closer to the navbar header.

I've been searching all day but everyone else seems to be asking about adding the hamburger menu.

Any suggestions?

http://codepen.io/anthkris/pen/xwpPrE/

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav id="mobile-nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container nav-mobile">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">K. Anthony</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li>
          <a href="#heading"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#portfolio"><i class="fa fa-file-photo-o"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#about-me"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- #mobile-nav -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
   .navbar-header {
       display: inline-block;
       float: left;
    }
}
```

Try this in media query this might help you.

Comment: Thanks! That works a treat! It's always something small.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the navigation to stay the same and just change icons you can try:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
   .navbar-header {
       float: left;
    }
   .navbar-nav {
       float: right;
    }
}
```

This will pull the header, which is your name to the left and the icons to the right. Keeping it the same as if you have it with the words.

Comment: Thanks, Victor. I was gonna ask that but figured it out with a little trial and error.